# How to solve the build error "cannot find -lc++" for an Android project in Qt Creator?

Tags: android, build, qt-creator

I followed the instruction to setup `Qt Creator` for `Android apps`. To check my setup I try to build and deploy the calculator example. I can successfully start the emulator and trigger a build for the app, but I get the following error:

```
/Users/burks/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld:
error: cannot find -lc++ clang++: error: linker command failed with
exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make: *** [libcalculator.so]
Error 1
```

I use Qt Creator vor macOS with a qt 5.12.3 installation for macOS and all Android Kits.

Comment: What's your Qt version?
https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/264903 says that 5.12.4 should fix this issue

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The linked page seems to describe my problem exactly. I have updated the Qt version for Qt Creator with the MaintenanceTool to 5.12.4 and reconfigured the project with the new kits. I also tried Qt version 5.13 but non of them solve the problem. I have installed Android SDK-Version: 26.1.1 and NDK-Version: 20.0.5594570 with Android Studio. I also installed NDK (side by side) just in case this has an impact.

Comment: Brian, it seems they didn't include fix in new release. Have same issues. I've tested many options last two days and the only working bundle is: sdk 29, ndk 17c, Qt 5.9.8. And on Ubuntu. Windows doesn't works in any way. Didn't try Qt 5.10 tho.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution from Albertino in a thread of the Qt Forum: https://forum.qt.io/topic/101322/what-s-the-problem-android-compile-error/12